# I need my correct MCPE skin

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I got out of a server called sg13 on Minecraft,my skin then changed to Alex.Whenever I tried to change my skin,I pressed the button to change it but then the screen went black and got out of the Minecraft app.It doesnt matter how many times I tried to change my skin it just got out of the app again.

Answer (score 1):

I HAVE AN ANSWER I've been having the exact problem OK so listen go get skinseed for minecraft by Africa's sunrise and if you have your skin use your skin as if you were going to edit it but unless you want to dont. Press export and then go Bach to mcpe the press the button it should work if it does than hurray if not I'm so sorry it worked for me

Comment: Please include sources to back up your answer.